# Google Oauth in functional components / Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: reactjs, google-oauth, google-authentication, react-functional-component

I beg your assistance on this. I'm using react  v16.13.1 and I have a class component which I want to convert to functional component.  My goal was to implement a google authenticate feature using functional components.

1. Should all class property be substitued by an State?  **this.auth** I've converted it to authState.
2. My functional component code returns this error from time to time. I assume this an asyncrony error and I should put an async function and its await inside the useEffect?

[functional component returns this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beAzM.png)
Thanks in advance for your time.

A. Class component

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"

class GoogleAuthButton extends Component {
  state = { isSignedIn: null }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.gapi.load("auth2", () => {
      window.gapi.auth2
        .init({
          client_id: process.env.REACT_APP_GAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
          scope: "email",
        })
        .then(() => {
          this.auth = window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
          // updating  state so component will re-render
          this.setState({ isSignedIn: this.auth.isSignedIn.get() })
        })
    })
  }


retrieveUserStatus() {
    if (this.state.isSignedIn === null) {
      return "UNKNOWN"
    } else if (this.state.isSignedIn) {
      return "SIGNED IN"
    } else {
      return "NOT SIGNED IN"
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Link to="/" className="item">
        <div>Status: {this.retrieveUserStatus()}</div>
      </Link>
    )
  }
}

export default GoogleAuth
```

B. Functional component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
const GoogleAuthButton = () => {
    const  [isSignedInState, isSignedInSetState] = useState({ isSignedIn: null });
    const  [authState, setAuthState] = useState({});
   
       useEffect(()=> {
// the following line arises the error:
                window.gapi.load("auth2", () => {
                window.gapi.auth2
                .init({
                    client_id: process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID, 
                    scope: "email",
                })
                .then(() => {
                    //gapi.auth2 becomes an state of our function component
                    setAuthState(window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance());
                    // update state so that component will re-render
                    isSignedInSetState({ isSignedIn: authState.isSignedIn.get() });
                                 
                })
            } )
        },[])


     // updates auth state to current auth status.It's triggered when authentication status changes
         const onAuthChange = () => {
            isSignedInSetState(authState.isSignedIn.get())
          }
     
        
        console.log("authentication", authState)


        return (
            <div>is the user signed in? {isSignedInState}</div>
        )

    
    }
```

I've added the google auth script in:
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
 
        <!-- GoogleAuth:--> 
  
   **<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>**
```

Comment: `window.gapi` is not loaded yet. I think this in unrelated to class/functional. Can you re-order your <scripts> to make sure  gapi is available when this component runs? Alternatives there may be some event you can listen for that it fires when ready.